# override transition animation isn't working targetting api 30 android

Tags: java, android

I am creating a new application.
My manifest looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.qawmilibrary">
    <activity android:name=".PdfActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".ArabicClassActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".DownloadListActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".WebviewAct"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.app.qawmilibrary.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
    </provider> <!-- Sample AdMob app ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713" />
</application>
```

And styles/themes

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.qawmilibrary" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">true</item>
</style>
<!-- Side Nav Theme -->
<style name="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.navTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Though all code is right but when I clicked it takes some time and get black screen.
Tried to make modification in every page that I can do, but in final its only black screen. I tried to find solution but nothing worked.

Update: Actual problem was in emulator. When I reboot emulator, then I get the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem was in the emulator. When I reboot my emulator as first I wipe the data and give a cold boot, then I get the solution.